# in react Redux how to structure app to decouple component from state atom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

in an redux app, using connect to fetch data from state is the way to go. problem is i find my self tighly coupling the component with the state atom.
in case i want to change the structure of the state tree, all components that used to consume such state will break.

so how to decouple them ?

example

```
initialState = {
 users: { ids:[1,2] , byId:{1:{name:'user 1'},2:{name:'user 2'} }
 posts: { ids:[1,2] , byId:{1:{title:'post 1'},2:{title:'post 1'} }
 access : {1:[1,2],2:[1,2]} //post_id : [user_id who can see post]
}
```

in this simple state, i'm descriping that i have 2 users, and 2 posts, both posts are visible to both users..

in a component that list posts and users the connect can be

```
render(){
let {posts,access,currentUser} = this.props;

let my_posts = posts.ids.map(post_id=>posts.byId[post_id])
                    .filter(post=>(access[post.id].indexOf(currentUser.id)>-1)
//above map will return posts, and filter will filterout posts user dont have access to.
}

connect( (state,prop)=>{currentUser:users[prop.user_id],posts,access})(Component);

<Component user_id={1} />
```

the problem here is that the render function of the component do lots of manipulation with the state to render correct data. it would be much better if i can do something like

```
render(){
let my_posts = Posts.ofUser(currentUser.id)
//now Posts should be a service that has access to state and return the needed data.
}
```

how can i create such Object that deals with the state and expose an api that components and connect functions contact for information.

i read about reselect alot, but how to implement it ?

Comment: check this example : https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart . And this video : https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux . it maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to decouple state shape from your components is querying any of your state prop through selectors.

It adds a bit of boilerplate code, but once is done, you'll get a fully testable bridge between your components and application state.

To get started with selectors, take a look to Redux Docs [Computing derivated data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) page.

Reselect is just an utility to create memoized selectors.